# Handling large pac files in C# HTTPWebRequest

Tags: .net, proxy, httpwebrequest, pac

I currently have a C# application which makes frequent web requests that have to potentially go through proxy authentication. In this situation, a large PAC file (200kb+) is used to automatically configure the proxy and is stored on a remote server.

When initializing the `HttpWebRequest` I have been setting the default proxy by using `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()` in the constructor of my connection class and then reusing the `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy` throughout the rest of my connection class.

Unfortunately this setup is extremely slow! I was wondering if a more efficient way of doing this exists.

Comment: Once the auto proxy code runs and proxy is initialized, there shouldnt be any more calls to get the proxy. Are you sure that the delay is due to the auto proxy code? If so, try setting the proxy server manually and retrying.